# What's best way to port an app written for froyo to support Honeycomb (esp tablets)?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-2.2-froyo

I have an app written and in market for froyo (phone). I want to expand this app to support honeycomb, specifically to support tablets. The tablet would have a more extensive UI/interface then that for the phone.

What's the best way to expand support for the froyo app to support tablets? Write another app for tablet, refactor the froyo app, or need to rewrite the whole app to support phone+tablet?

Also, if I am supporting phone+tablet, is that possible in one codebase?

Answer (score 2):

Best to use the Android Compatibility Package and Fragments.

Comment: Agreed. No point in re-writing the entire application. Refactor into Fragments using the compatibility package.